# Maven is attempting to download parent pom from central on different goals

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have several projects at my company that all share a parent pom.  Some of the projects work fine.  However in others when Jenkins tries to build it, it tries to download the parent pom from:

```
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/....
```

instead of

```
http://localnexus/com/....
```

Sometimes it happens during the site goal, more recently its reared its head during the sonar phase.

Jenkins is using the same settings file for all the builds.  Some work and some don't.  None of the projects are defining any repositories.  I can not discern any difference in the projects as to why this is happening.

I have tried to override the site plugin etc... to no avail, but its not even happening in the site right now.

I have also tried different maven versions.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

**some updates from comments  --THANKS-- **

1. the Jenkins job runs mvn install deploy site and it gets the parent and does that successfully, when it does it downloads all the dependancies from from our nexus site correctly.  It only fails when trying to get the parent pom.  And now only when it tries to do a post build action in Jenkins on the Sonar.
2. We thought we had a workaround by releasing the parent poms with a '-RELEASE' notation.   That has proven to only work in a couple instances.
3. This is on a window box, but i can repeat the failures on my mac via commandline.  For one project if i put the '-RELEASE' it will work, and fail (as described above), but when it goes to Jenkins it will fail either way.

Comment: Only explanation can be that the projects that are working in Jenkins are using a Maven installation with the correct settings.xml, whereas the ones that don't work are using a different Maven installation with default settings.xml (which doesn't contain any reference to your local nexus server). Are you running jenkins on a Unix/Linux box?

Comment: Another question: when you run from the command line, do all projects build correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I was actually having 2 issues.  But they were both failing the same way.
The first was actually a failure in the build template of the sonar job .  It could not find the global settings file.  However it was a message in the log file, but tucked away as apart of another log message.
The 2nd issues was fixed by this post:

[How can I get the maven-site-plugin to resolve the parent pom.xml of my multimodule Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366056/how-can-i-get-the-maven-site-plugin-to-resolve-the-parent-pom-xml-of-my-multimod)

Read the accepted answer and apply Laird Nelson's 2nd option.

Both of those resulted in the the parent pom to be located in central.  I understand the first, the 2nd seems to be a bug.

But after battling the 2nd for some time, seeing the same problem I immediately went to that as the cause.

Thanks for comments and suggestions.